# AngularJS ui grid edit not working with group

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular ui-grid, it is working fine but when I apply grouping from option, edit functionality not working.

Please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HK7N2Z5WR9Q0ZrNSsnvE?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.grouping', 'ui.grid.pinning','ui.grid.exporter','ui.grid.selection']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.columns = [

    //Below line is with default groupby functionality (If we uncomment below line edit functionality on cell double click is not working)
    { field: 'GHC', grouping: { groupPriority: 1 }, pinnedLeft: true}, 
    //Below line is with without groupby functionality (If we comment above line and uncomment below line  edit functionality on cell double click is working as expected)
    //{ field: 'GHC',  pinnedLeft: true}, 

    { field: 'Status', filter: {
          type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, 
          selectOptions: [ { value: 'Active', label: 'Active' }, { value: 'Won', label: 'Won' }, { value: 'Lost', label: 'Lost'}, { value: 'InActive', label: 'InActive' }]
        }
    },
    { field: 'Region' },
    { field: 'Country' },
    { field: 'City' },
    { field: 'Industry'},
    {  field: 'SubIndustry',displayName: 'SubIndustry' }, 
    { field: 'Date Of Win' }];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    exporterMenuCsv: true,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv',
    columnDefs: $scope.columns
  }
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks to me like the problem is that group header rows don't allow editing.  When the grid first renders all the groups are collapsed, so none of the rows are editable.  When you expand to show some detail rows we reuse the DOM, and the editable property isn't re-evaluated.  In short, you've found a bug.  I suggest you raise an issue, I can look at it as part of some work I'm doing on grouping at the moment.

Comment: can you give a quick solution for that, if you have any idea about that. thanks in advance

Comment: You can edit your ui-grid.js, about line 17666, in the `insertGroupHeader` function, delete the line `headerRow.enableCellEdit = false;`

Comment: I've done a full patch in unstable, which preserves the fact that group header rows shouldn't be editable.  But this is part of a big grouping rewrite which might still be quite unstable - and has some breaking changes.  You may want to wait a little while for it to stabilise a bit.